# How can I make fixed div appear without page automatically scrolling back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using JQuery to make a fixed div appear on top right corner, regardless of the position of the page. But when div appears on clicking link, the page automatically scrolls back to the top of the page. How can I make it stop doing that. It should appear on top right of the window without affecting the page. (I've tried both, display and visibility properties).

**CSS**

```
  #contactDetails {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 3;
      left : calc(100% - 300px);
      top : 70px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

**JS**

```
  $(".fa-phone, .fa-envelope").click(function(){
        $("#contactDetails").css("visibility","visible");
      // $("#contactDetails").show( );
  });
```

Comment: please post HTML code also

Answer (score 1):

Are fa-phone and fa-envelope links? Do they have href="#" or similar?

If so then the link is taking you back to the top of the page.

Either, stop using links for purposes other than linking. Or cancel the default action of the link inside your function -https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/